# Updating a model instance with foreign key through Django generic update view.

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have a django model called "classifieds" which as name suggests is a classified database.Each instance of classifeds will have multiple images attached to it. So created another model named "ClassifiedImage" and associated to "classified" model via foreign key. I want to utilize Django generic update view to update "classified" model but generic views accepts only one model and form instance (please see below *). But currently generic views allow me to display only 1 form (in this case "classifiedForm) which i can update the classified model but not able to edit images of that specific instance. Keep in mind that classifiedImage models where the images are stored and linked via foreign key.

```
views.py


    def add_classified(request):
          userprofile = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

          if request.method == 'POST':
              form = classifiedForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
              if form.is_valid():
                  classifiedad = form.save(commit=False)
                  image_formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=classifiedad)
                  classifiedad.submitted_by = request.user
                  classifiedad.save()
                  image_formset.save()
                  slug = classifiedad.slug
                  redirect_to =reverse('classified-detail', kwargs={'slug':slug})
                  return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
          else:
              form = classifiedForm()
              image_formset = ImageFormSet()
          return render_to_response('shclassified/add_classified.html',{'form':form, 'image_formset':image_formset},context_instance = RequestContext(request))

      def classified_list(request):
          classified_list = classified.objects.all()
          return render_to_response('classified_list.html',
              {'classified_list':classified_list},
              context_instance = RequestContext(request)
              )

      def classified_detail(request,slug):
              classifiedinst = classified.objects.get(slug=slug)
              classifiedimg = ClassifiedImage.objects.filter(classified=classifiedinst)
              '''Create a string representation of classified's address so it can be geocoded'''
              classified_address = "%s %s %s %s"%(classifiedinst.address, classifiedinst.city, classifiedinst.state, classifiedinst.zipcode)
              lat, lng = getLatLng(classified_address)
              constructed_map = getMap(lat, lng, largeMap=False)
              #Get user's full name
              return render_to_response('shclassified/classified_detail.html',
              {
                  'classifiedimg':classifiedimg,
                  'user':request.user,
                  'classified':get_object_or_404(classified,slug=slug),
                  'constructed_map':constructed_map,
                  },
              context_instance = RequestContext(request)
              )
#I NEED TO BE ABLE TO UPDATE THE IMAGES HERE IN THIS VIEW AS WELL. DELETE, REPLACE    #IMAGES ETC...Perhaps generic views are not designed for this purpose?
class ClassifiedUpdate(UpdateView):
     model = classified# ****** <=== ***
     form_class = classifiedForm **** <=== ***
     template_name = 'shclassified/add_classified.html'
```

Models.py

```
**class classified(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=settings.SRID, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        #return "%s %s %s"%(self.title, self.point.x, self.point.y)
        return "%s"%(self.title)
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('listing_detail', (),
                    {
                        'slug' :self.slug,
                    })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        if not self.point:
            location = "%s+%s+%s+%s"%(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
            cord = get_lat_long(location)
            x,y = cord.split(",")
            x = float(x)
            y = float(y)
            self.point = Point(x,y)
            self.point2 = Point(x,y)
            super(classified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class ClassifiedImage(models.Model):
        classified = models.ForeignKey(classified, related_name="images")
        #image = ImageField()
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='classifieds/%Y/%m/%d',  default='static/img/no-thumb.jpg', null=True, blank=True)**
```

Forms.py

```
class classifiedForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = classified
          exclude = ["user","point","submitted_by","slug"]

ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(classified, ClassifiedImage, can_delete = False)
```